# Правильное написание окончания

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, деловой-язык

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно просклонять слово ("выполнение" или "выполнению") из названия документа: «Договор на оказание услуг по техническому обслуживанию и выполнение работ по ремонту оргтехники для нужд ООО "Ромашка"»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Договор на оказание услуг по техническому обслуживанию и **выполнение** работ по ремонту оргтехники для нужд ООО "Ромашка."

Правильное управление: договор на **оказание** услуг и **выполнение** работ (на что? В.п.).

В сокращенной записи: Договор на техническое обслуживание и ремонт оргтехники.